# Ajax replace html with response but load content after css,js are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I need to replace entire html with ajax response. I tried this:

```
      $.ajax({                                   
         type: "GET",                           
         url: url                                     
       }).done(function(response) {
            document.documentElement.innerHTML = response;               
      });
```

Which replaces html, but the problem is that it won't wait css and js files (from the new html) to be loaded before new body is rendered. For this reason it shows broken css for some ms (because css files from head of new page are loaded after body tags are displayed) and it also shows some js errors (for the same reason).

I need to load css and js files from head in the same order as they are located and NOT asynchronously. Is there any solution to this problem?

As example, you can just put this into console in a browser that didn't cache stackoverflow css yet:

```
$.ajax({                                   
   type: "GET",                           
   url: window.location.origin                                     
 }).done(function(response) {
      document.documentElement.innerHTML = response;               
});
```

But the real scenario is more complicated. The page I am calling has a lot of javascript. Javascript is defined in head as external and internal script and it have to be loaded in the same order as it is there.

Comment: It looks like you're injecting into a subnode of body, so maybe you can put the ajax call into an onload handler that won't fire until the css from head is already loaded.

Comment: I am talking about css, js files from the new page that I am loading it with ajax, not existing.

Comment: So you are injecting a new head and body into the existing page?

Comment: How about temp inserting it into an invisible DOM element and when the content is loaded, replace the whole HTML with it?

Comment: @DovRine As wrote the above, I am replacing the entire html. Not injecting and mixing it with existing one, I need to replace entire html.

Comment: In your code, what is document.documentElement? Is that the html tag? Never mind. It has to be.

Comment: @MauriceNino I could just hide the body with css until everything is loaded, no need to create invisible element. But the problem is still how to load all css,js files NOT asynchronously but in the same order as they are there. With document.documentElement.innerHTML = response; it will just load everything from response in the same time.

Comment: Can you add an example response that we can test with?

Comment: Sure, I will prepare it in 5 minutes.

Comment: Based on what you've said so far, I'm thinking that you might need to parse the response yourself and then rebuild the DOM piecemeal.

Comment: @JohnClark Yeah but you don't have to show broken HTML/CSS for the few ms then if you just wait with the replacement until its actually loaded.

Comment: @JohnClark: I can't reproduce with your example. My connection might be too fast. I think that I can create a test example, though. I'll post an answer if I come up with anything.

Comment: "The page I am calling has a lot of javascript. Javascript is defined in head as external and internal script and it have to be loaded in the same order as it is there." Why is it loading synchronously from the original page?

Comment: Since you're replacing the entire page anyway, maybe a redirect or an iframe would work better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SetTimeout method and set some seconds of delay to render the HTML from the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily insert it into a `div`, that is not displayed, then wait for the content to load and finally replace the real HTML with the content like in this example snippet:

```js
$.ajax({                                   
  type: "GET",                           
  url: url                                     
}).done(function(response) {
  let temp = document.getElementById('tempSaver');
  temp.innerHTML = response; // Insert content in invisible div
  
  setTimeout(() => { // After 1 second replace the real HTML
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = temp.innerHTML;
    temp.innerHTML = '';
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#tempSaver {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div id="tempSaver">
  </div>
</html>
```

#### Note

While I use `setTimeout` it would be better if you can specify the content that needs to be loaded (for example the CSS file) and check if that is loaded and only replace it when that case comes into play.